# Cocos2D-X - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0) when initializing a CCTMXTiledMap

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to create a game in Cocos2D-X with a tile map and I'm getting the below error:

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)** in the line **setContentSize(CCSizeZero);** of the method **CCTMXTiledMap::initWithTMXFile(const char *tmxFile)**

I'm creating the tile map in this way:

```
tileMap->initWithTMXFile("TileMap.tmx");
this->background = tileMap->layerNamed("Background");
```

Somebody knows what it's happening?

Please, could you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem. Just a little of theory:

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2** means that the pointer is corrupt and this could happen because:

- The pointer could have never been initialized.
- The pointer could have been accidentally written over because you overstepped the bounds of an array.
- The pointer could be part of an object that was casted incorrectly, and then written to.
- Any of the above could have corrupted a different pointer that now points at or near this pointer, and using that one corrupts this one (and so on).

So, in my case, I thought that `initWithTMXFile` was good enough to initialize the `tileMap` pointer but I was wrong. The solution is that first thing before `initWithTMXFile`, `tileMap` must be initialized. So, the correct block of code is:

```
this->tileMap = new CCTMXTiledMap();
this->tileMap->initWithTMXFile("TileMap.tmx");
this->background = tileMap->layerNamed("Background");
this->addChild(tileMap);
```

I hope it helps.