# tread 1 error - using rand()function

Tags: c++, random

I have to select random number between 0 and 3. I have to call this function several times. In the beginning it's always working but after some time the error message `Tread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code =2, address 0x7fff5f3ffff8` appears.

Here is my code. `m_p[multiproject][project]` is equal to `4`;

```
int selecteer_random_resource(int multiproject, int project)
{   int k=0;
    k=rand()%m_p[multiproject][project];
    return k;
}
```

I really don't understand why it's working in the beginning and after some time the error appears.

Comment: Really depends on what `m_p`, `multiproject`, and `project` are don't you think?  Try editing the code into a short complete example.

Comment: Look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363513/cocos2d-x-exc-bad-access-code-2-address-0x0-when-initializing-a-cctmxtiledm and try your debugger

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` is **not** thread safe, and it says so in the documentation.
Citing https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161352/4433386:

> That said, the documentation states:
>
> > The function rand() is not **reentrant or thread-safe**, since it uses hidden state that is modified on each call. This might just be the
> >     seed value to be used by the next call, or it might be something more
> >     elaborate. In order to get reproducible behaviour in a threaded
> >     application, this state must be made explicit. The function rand_r()
> >     is supplied with a pointer to an unsigned int, to be used as state.
> >     This is a very small amount of state, so this function will be a weak
> >     pseudo-random generator. Try drand48_r(3) instead.
>
> The emphasized part of the above is probably the reason why all your
>   threads get the same number.

You should, especially in the year 2015, use a thread safe random number generator. Boost/C++11 has the [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) standard library, containing awesome methods to thread-safely generate random numbers.

If you can't use boost or C++11, you can also try `drand`, e.g. [`drand48_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/drand48_r).